# Overloading JavaFX Bindings

Tags: javafx, binding, overriding, overloading, subclassing

I am binding two labels, calculating the value of the second label via a series of nested calls to Bindings.when().  Since I'm doing the exact same thing 3 times in a row to 3 similar labels, is there a way to simplify this code by overloading one of the Bindings methods or IntegerBinding methods?

```
private IntegerProperty ipStrength, ipAgility, ipIntelligence;
private IntegerProperty ipStBonus, ipAgBonus, ipInBonus;


public RolePlayingCharacter() {

    ...

    ipStBonus.bind(Bindings.when(ipStrength.lessThan(5))
            .then(-1)
            .otherwise(Bindings.when(ipStrength.lessThan(9))
                    .then(0)
                    .otherwise(Bindings.when(ipStrength.lessThan(11))
                            .then(1)
                            .otherwise(2))));

    ipAgBonus.bind(Bindings.when(ipAgility.lessThan(5))
            .then(-1)
            .otherwise(Bindings.when(ipAgility.lessThan(9))
                    .then(0)
                    .otherwise(Bindings.when(ipAgility.lessThan(11))
                            .then(1)
                            .otherwise(2))));

    ipInBonus.bind(Bindings.when(ipIntelligence.lessThan(5))
            .then(-1)
            .otherwise(Bindings.when(ipIntelligence.lessThan(9))
                    .then(0)
                    .otherwise(Bindings.when(ipIntelligence.lessThan(11))
                            .then(1)
                            .otherwise(2))));

    ...
```

I have found I can Override Class IntegerBinding's computeValue method, but this doesn't seem to help any, since I would have to do the some thing 3 times anyway, once for each label:

```
    IntegerBinding ibStatBonus = new IntegerBinding() {
        {
            super.bind(ipStrength);
        }

        @Override
        protected int computeValue() {
            int iStatValue = ipStrength.get();
            if (iStatValue < 5) {
                return -1;
            } else if (iStatValue < 9) {
                return 0;
            } else if (iStatValue < 11) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }
        }
    };
```

I want to be able to do something simple like:

```
    ipStBonus.bind(ipStrength.calculateStatBonus());
    ipAgBonus.bind(ipAgility.calculateStatBonus());
    ipInBonus.bind(ipIntelligence.calculateStatBonus());
```

How do I implement such a thing?  How do I make a caclulateStatBonus method part of the list of methods available to an IntegerProperty?

Answer (score 1):

It's always possible to create a helper method for this:

```
public static IntegerBinding createStatBonusBinding(final IntegerProperty source) {
    return Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
        int value = source.get();
        if (value < 5) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (value < 9) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (value < 11) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 2;
    }, source);
}
```

```
ipStBonus.bind(createStatBonusBinding(ipStrength));
ipAgBonus.bind(createStatBonusBinding(ipAgility));
ipInBonus.bind(createStatBonusBinding(ipIntelligence));
```